# Is it possible to label a postgis Query Layer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcmap, postgresql, arcgis-10.2

I've created a PostGIS query layer and I can't label it. I'm trying to work out if I'm dealing with a bug that I can't workaround, a bug that I can workaround, or if it is operator error.

After getting my table and columns to lower case and making sure my [data types are supported](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//019v00000002000000), I was able to add a query, validate, pick the OID column and add it to ArcMap. I can view the attribute table and identify attributes (point) with no problem.

ArcMap crashes (no error--just disappears) when I turn on labels, which are coming from  a `character varying(400)` field.

Has anyone run into this and knows what is going on?

Here's what I'm running:

Client:
ArcMap 10.2.1 10.2.1.3497

Database:
"PostgreSQL 9.3.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit  ,  PostGIS:2.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I worked out the issue--I replaced the `ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin\libpq.dll` file with one for postgresql 9.3 (32-bit):
http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-9.3.5-1-windows-binaries.zip

I replaced it, restart ArcMap and I am now able to label.